# Multi-currency prepaid card for Brazilian residents

Tags: payment-cards, brazil, multi-currency

I'm Brazilian resident and I'm looking for a bank account (with IBAN and international card) or a prepaid multi-currency which I can deposit sending money online using platforms such as TransferWise.

I've been looking for a while with so many solutions and I haven't found anyone which supports me. To list some I searched for:

- TransferWise (don't send cards to Brazil).
- N26 (don't open account for non eu/usa residents)
- Revolut (same as n26)
- Leupay (same as n26)
- Naga (same as n26)

I'm trying to avoid the high taxes to buy euros from Currency Exchanges paying for tourism euro. I'm looking for real euro taxes. Transferwise offer it to me, but I don't have a card to store that money to spend and withdraw abroad.

Comment: What means resident for you ? Who live in Europe? you can open a N26 account as a non EU/US resident having a Valid EU address. I have opened and sent for a friend address in Europe

Comment: Technically, N26 _does_ open accounts for non EU/USA residents, since they don't really need you to _live_ there, they just need an address (and, of course, the kind of account you open will be tied to that country, something I'll return to in a second).

So if you have a friend who lives in the EU, for instance, that you trust enough to receive the card for you, you could use their address.

BUT the thing is you have to take into account the aforemetioned fact: if you open the account with an UK address, you won't have an IBAN number - but you don't need that for Transferwise anyway.

Comment: And if you open the account with an EU address, you will pay fees for using the card / making withdrawals in the UK.

Comment: And I don't know if the N26 account is "multi-currency".

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'm going give a try and look for some EU address and, if it works to me, I'll post the answer later.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it's difficult to deduce your underlying use-case, and it appears your issue might be more suited to something like expats.se.

That said, you might be served by the ecosystem that's provided through becoming an e-resident of Estonia. That would make it possible for you to open a bank account in Estonia, as well as a few other European countries, and to receive money into those bank accounts from outside of Brazil, while also having access to that account within Brazil.

More info:

https://e-resident.gov.ee

(I'm an Estonian e-resident residing in Brazil.)